Eigenvectors of Johnson Graph $J(N,2)$
I am having trouble finding an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors of the Johnson Graph $J(N,k)$ with k=2 in an explicit form. In the paper "On the reconstruction of eigenfunctions of Johnson graphs" https://doi.org/10.1016/j.dam.2019.02.034 there is a component-wise description of them
\begin{equation}
    v^{b}_{a} = \frac{E_{d(a,b)}(i,k,N)}{\binom{k}{d(a,b)}\binom{N-k}{d(a,b)}}
\end{equation}
Where $b$ is any vertex of the graph, and $i$ is the kind of eigenvalue whose eigenvector they are. The problem is that they are not orthogonal after computing the scalar products between them. Instead, I get something like
\begin{equation}
   \langle v^b, v^c \rangle = 2\delta_{bc} - 1
\end{equation}
when $i=1,2$. This would mean that they are not orthogonal in the eigenspace but also between the two different eigenspaces, which I do not think should be happening. On the other hand, a paper about an orthogonal basis of the Johnson graph's eigenvectors seems to exist: https://doi.org/10.37236/4567, but I cannot extract the entry-wise description I look for.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

When I try this computation in Mathematica for $J(10,3)$ (chosen somewhat arbitrarily), at the very least all the vectors with $i=1$ are orthogonal to all the vectors with $i=2$, as they should be. The only lack of orthogonality is within an eigenspace.

@MishaLavrov How do you choose the different bs? For every I you get the same number of possible eigenvectors but you know only a subset of them are linearly independent as the dimension of the eigenspace is less

I just checked that all $\binom{10}3$ eigenvectors for $\lambda_1$ that the formula gave were orthogonal to all $\binom{10}3$ eigenvectors for $\lambda_2$. Sure, they won't be all independent. (Mostly, I was concerned about your claim that vectors from different eigenspaces were not orthogonal, which would mean something going really wrong; I was unable to reproduce this.)

@MishaLavrov Thanks, that was my main issue too but probably I am getting something wrong in computing the scalar products. Still, if you happen to know any  explicit entrywise representation for the orthogonalized eigenvectors I would be grateful

@MishaLavrov Btw can you confirm from your Mathematica computation that the scalar products of the same kind eigenvectors are of the like $<v_i,v_j> = C\delta_{ij} + Q$?

In the case I looked at, each $\lambda_1$-eigenvector had a norm of $\sqrt{\frac{40}{3}}$ and a dot product in ${\frac{440}{63}, \frac{40}{63}, -\frac{40}{7}}$ with the other $\lambda_1$-eigenvectors, depending on graph distance. Similar things happen to the $\lambda_i$-eigenvectors for other $i$.
